# mysql performance: store Boolean values (flags) in one row as an aggregated number or not?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, boolean

MySQL table `mytable` structure is:

```
Name - param1 - param2 - param3 - param4 - param5 - ... - param20.
```

`param<number>` has boolean type ( TINYINT(1) )

Let's say I want to execute a query:

```
SELECT Name FROM mytable WHERE param4=1 AND param7=1;
```

Everything works as expected.

If I'm curious about **performance**, then is that OK to have the aggregated column `params` instead of `param1, param2, ... param20`?

For this purpose, I would store all Boolean parameters an one integer number.

For example, `72 = 64+8 = 0+0*2+0*4+1*8+0*16+0*32+1*64+0+...+0` would correspond 
`param4=true` and `param7=true`, 
all others are `false`. This is easy.

However, will that significantly impact on performance of Select queries to extract the same rows as the query above?
I believe the query would be

```
SELECT Name FROM mytable WHERE (params % 16 = 8) AND (params % 128 = 64);
```

I think the aggregated value (and as result only two columns) is better, but what about the performance?

Any pitfalls?

Thank you.

Comment: Use a bit field as data type

Comment: The pitfall of making your database schema and code less easy to understand at a glance, is the performance currently a problem?

Comment: @paul However I don't have 20 columns and the additional parameter may be implemented easily (I don't need additional column for this purpose). Also, the weight of the table is less (in megabytes).

Comment: I'm not sure you'll gain much by transforming 8 `TINYINT` fields into one `BIT` field (speed or space) - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: @Paul, the question is about SELECT query performance, not about space. It has more arithmetical operations inside of it, however the table has less columns in the second case. Which is faster/better - that was the question.

Comment: Performance would be hit, because you cannot use indexes to seek through your params. Only do something like this if it's read into code and used elsewhere and not for filtering in the database.

Comment: @Allan S. Hansen Do you mean to use indexes for all 20 columns? Also, will indexes help a lot if the values are only true and false in there?

Comment: I'd not put an individual index on all twenty columns, but if you use the twenty columns for filtering, I'd likely have some (based on actual data usage analysis) in some indexes. Your actual real data might behave different than the shown and that's why it requires some analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with bit operations of course is that if at some point in the future your database would benefit from indexing these values, you're somewhat stuck.

Unless you have a really compelling reason not to, I would say go with seperate fields. The database is designed to track different pieces of information - we shouldn't be trying to impress it with another approach - it's optimised for tracking different information in different columns.

Answer (score 1):

Even very experienced DBA under estimate the CPU cost of functions and operators in queries. For best performance, keep it simple. If for whatever reason in the future you have to make a massive query or a query with higher computational complexity ; it may be a performance issue to handle even a simple modulo.